# How to prevent FirebaseListAdapter from updating when listview is scrolled?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to implement Firebase Android chat that updates only when ListView with messages is scrolled to the bottom where new messages appear. (that's how chat works in twitch for example, to let users read old messages with comfort).

Here's what I tried:

**MyFirebaseListAdapter** (modified FirebaseListAdapter)

```
public abstract class MyFirebaseListAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    MyFirebaseArray mSnapshots;
    ...
    public void setShouldUpdate(boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            mSnapshots.addEventListener();
        } else {
            mSnapshots.removeEventListener();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**MyFirebaseArray** (modified FirebaseArray)

```
class MyFirebaseArray implements ChildEventListener {
    ...
    private boolean hasEventListener = false;
    ...
    public void removeEventListener() {
        if (!hasEventListener) return;
        hasEventListener = false;
        mQuery.removeEventListener(this);
    }
    public void addEventListener() {
        if (hasEventListener) return;
        hasEventListener = true;
        mSnapshots.clear();
        mQuery.addChildEventListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

**ChatActivity**

```
final MyFirebaseListAdapter adapter = new MyFirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(ChatActivity.this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.li_chat_message, db.child("/messages/" + room.key).limitToLast(40)) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, final ChatMessage msg, int position) {
        ChatUtils.layoutChatMessage(ChatActivity.this, db, user, status, v, msg, bgColor, new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                etMessage.setText(msg.author.name + ", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
};
lvMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
lvMessages.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
            adapter.setShouldUpdate(true);
        } else {
            adapter.setShouldUpdate(false);
        }
    }
});
```

However, this throws me the following **exception** if I'm changing scrolling direction at the bottom too quick:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 34, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.kg.app.***.chat.adapter.MyFirebaseArray.getItem(MyFirebaseArray.java:80)
at com.kg.app.***.chat.adapter.MyFirebaseListAdapter.getItem(MyFirebaseListAdapter.java:117)
at com.kg.app.***.chat.adapter.MyFirebaseListAdapter.getView(MyFirebaseListAdapter.java:147)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
at android.widget.ListView.correctTooHigh(ListView.java:1421)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:663)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4995)
at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4543)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

**UPDATE**

I know that exception is thrown because I clear mSnapshots array in addEventListener() method. But if i remove this line all records duplicate each time addEventListener is called. Also if I'm scrolling slowly my solution works fine.

Comment: Have you tried [Firebase UI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)?

Comment: I'm using this library, but original FirebaseListAdapter class doesn't provide api for disabling child listener